# Does GDPR replace EU cookie notice policy?

Tags: gdpr, eu-cookie-law

From what I understand GDPR says you are not allowed to store user identification information such us IP, name. But I could use cookies for user experience. For example I can track visited page categories/products to show related products.

Original cookie law from years ago restricted also that. In old cookie law you were not allowed to store cookies without consent if cookie was not required for functionality (e.g. shopping cart, login). User experience cookies required consent. So I could not show related products based on activity (e.g. visited categories, purchase history, number of visited pages, ...) if user didn't agree.

- Does GDPR replace cookie notice law?
- Do I still need to use a cookie notice?

Answer (score 3):

The cookie notice/consent is apart of the Directive 2002/58/EC while The EU General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) replaces the 
95/46/EC Data Protection Directive.

They are not the same but work in a relationship. You will need to ensure your site complies with [DIRECTIVE 2002/58/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32002L0058) and [REGULATION (EU) 2016/679](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679) , most often complying with one may comply with the other on certain things. You need to do your own research or use a GDPR generator.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in the GDPR it says you are not allowed to store user identification information.

What the GDPR states is that *if* you collect or process personal data (i.e. any data that can be linked to a certain individual) you need to be transparant to the data subject about *why* you use his/her personal data, and what you are doing with it – especially if you share it with other parties. This is usually communicated through a privacy statement, shown when first visiting a website.

Comment: can you provide a link to substantiate your claims?

Comment: A link to substantiate my claims? You could try making an effort and actually read the regulation, as I did.

Comment: Richard, you are a new contributor so you may not understand that part of the purpose of Stack Exchange is to create a lasting archive of answers.  That includes links to resources that will help others in future.  I am not interested in the question or your answer or even the regulations, but I am interested in helping make SE work into the future.

Comment: Sorry Steve, I've encountered a few trolls elsewhere when trying to have an adult discussion on the subject and I guess the way you phrased your question triggered me.

Comment: [Algolia](https://gdpr.algolia.com) offers a handy search engine on the regulation's text.

Comment: A key article to support the above is Recital #39: "Any processing of personal data should be lawful and fair. It should be transparent to natural persons that personal data concerning them are collected, used, consulted or otherwise processed and to what extent the personal data are or will be processed". 

As you will see this recital is all about processing personal data and having a legitimate ground for it.